# How to call WebAPI from another application by passing parameters into Web URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to call WebAPI from another application and perform some operations, I'm trying to pass parameters from one application into web api through URL but it does not hit in the web api when I'm calling the web api.

I have created one web application and one web api application. I have added one html template into web app and an image with src tag which contains web api uri and trying to pass parameters through that uri, I'm trying to debug web api 
by adding breakpoints, whenever an image loads into web app it is not hitting it in web api. (both are my apps in running mode.)

**Here is my html template:**

```
<form method="get">
    <img src="http://localhost:59800/TrackEmail?fromemail={fromemail}&toemail={toemail}&uid={uid}" height="0" width="0" />
</form>
```

**Here is my web api code:**

```
public class TrackEmailController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/TrackEmail")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult TrackEmail([FromUri]string fromemail, [FromUri]string toemail, [FromUri]string uid)
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;
        var agent = request.Browser.Browser;
        SaveTrack(uid, fromemail, toemail, DateTime.Now, "R", agent);
        return Ok();
    }

    private OracleConnection ocon;

    private void connection()
    {
        //oracle database connection
    }

    public void SaveTrack(string uid, string fromEmail, string toEmail, DateTime date_time, string flag, string agent)
    {
        connection();
        //database code
    }
}
```

**Here my WebApiConfig.cs code:**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MailApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{fromemail}/{toemail}/{uid}",
            defaults: new { fromemail = RouteParameter.Optional, toemail = RouteParameter.Optional, uid = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What can be the issue? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    **[Route("api/TrackEmail")]**
```

you're routing incorrectly, missing the "api/"
try

```
<form method="get">
<img src="http://localhost:59800/api/TrackEmail?fromemail={fromemail}&toemail={toemail}&uid={uid}" height="0" width="0" />
</form>
```